# tabular* with rubber spacing and \cline

Tags: tables, spacing, rules

I'm using a `tabular*` with rubber spacing to fill the complete width of the page. This works fine, except that when I use `\cline`, the line is not complete. It seems that `\cline` does not cover the spacing. I'm using `pdflatex`. Below you will find a code example. Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
 \usepackage{array} % for defining a new column type
 \usepackage{varwidth} %for the varwidth minipage environment
 %...
 \newcolumntype{M}{>{\begin{varwidth}{6cm}}l<{\end{varwidth}}} %M is for Maximal column
 %...
 \begin{tabular*}{15.5cm}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} | M | r | r | r | r |}
   \hline
   \bf Omschrijving & \bf Hoeveelheid & \bf Prijs & \bf SubTotaal & \bf BTW\\
   \hline
   Armband 2 & 1 & 256.00 & 256.00 & 19.00\% \\
   \hline
   \multicolumn{3}{c |}{} & SubTotaal & 256.00\\
   \multicolumn{3}{c |}{} & BTW (19.0) & 48.64\\
   \multicolumn{3}{c |}{}  & \bf Totaal & \bf 304.64\\
   \cline{4-5}
\end{tabular*}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's caused by `\extracolsep{\fill}` which produces the space that `\cline` doesn't fill. You could verify that by removing `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}`.

Besides removing that rubber length, you could repair it by

- inserting another one such as

`\begin{tabular*}{15.5cm}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}| M | r | r |@{\extracolsep{0pt}}r | r |}`

- or by using a width-fitting tabular environment which adjust the columns width instead of the column separation: [`tabularx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx). This would be my choice.

Further I strongly recommend to omit all these vertical lines which obstruct the reading. Good tables don't need to be grids! Have a look at the [`booktabs`](http://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) package and its documentation. I would use perhaps a top line, a seperation line below the header and a bottom line, but no vertical line at all. Compare tables in good books, you're able to typeset fine tables too.

Comment: I actually tried using "@{\extracolsep{0pt}" but that did not work. Was I doing something wrong? Did this work for you? However, I strongly second the "tabularx" and "booktabs" suggestions. Those are my preferred packages anyday.

Comment: @Jimi: It worked for me, I tested it. In your comment, a closing brace is missing. Could this be the reason? Otherwise I could post a minimal working example.

Comment: This works, but it also removes the spacing. The longest text is against the left line. I guess this is logical as @{\extracolsep{0pt}} removes the spacing. I will look into  tabularx for a better solution.

Comment: @Stephan: spacing could be done within the column, by `\makebox` or `\hspace` for instance. But `tabularx` is better because that already adjusts column inner width.

Comment: I had the closing brace but my problem was I placed @{\extracolsep{0pt}} in the wrong column. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an answer, but I would like to say that the from a bit of fiddling around it would seem that `\extracolsep` doesn't play very nicely with `\cline` regardless of the rubberlength

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{|@{\extracolsep{1cm}}{l}@{\extracolsep{1cm}}|r|c|@{\extracolsep{0cm}}}
    \cline{1-3} 
    one&two&three\\    \cline{2-3}
    one&two&three\\    \cline{1-2}
    one&two&three\\    \cline{2-2}
    one&two&three\\    \cline{3-3}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

results in:

[image]

There are a few things that are wrong:

- Why is the first column so squished?
- Why isn't there space added to the right and left of every column?
- Why are the clines not going all the way to the verticals?

I know that this is not an answer... and I apologize, if people think that I should repost this as a question, I'd happily do that. Just to appease the gods, I've marked this answer CW so that people can convert the question into a real answer, as I think that there are issues here that are very relevant to the original question.

Comment: `\extracolsep` affects subsequent columns but will not insert space before the first column. Leslie Lamport wrote this in his book "A Document Preparation System" which is kind of a reference manual. However, for the first column a `@{\hspace{1cm}` would work.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned before (without example), this is provided by the [`tabularx` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx).

More specifically, it provides the `X` column type that stretches that specific column as needed to fill the width of the table.

Common usage has the format:

```
\usepackage{tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx
...
\begin{tabularx}{<width>}{..X..X..}
  ...
\end{tabularx}
```

Here is your minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{array}% http://ctan.org/pkg/array
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{tabularx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx
\begin{document}
    %\newcolumntype{M}{>{\begin{varwidth}{6cm}}l<{\end{varwidth}}} %M is for Maximal column
    
    \noindent%
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{| p{6cm} | X | X | X | X |}
        \hline
        \textbf{Omschrijving} & \textbf{Hoeveelheid} & \textbf{Prijs} & \textbf{SubTotaal} & \textbf{BTW} \\     \hline
        Armband 2 & 1 & 256.00 & 256.00 & 19.00\% \\     \hline
        \multicolumn{3}{c |}{} & SubTotaal & 256.00 \\     \multicolumn{3}{c |}{} & BTW (19.0) & 48.64 \\     \multicolumn{3}{c |}{} & \textbf{Totaal} & \textbf{304.64} \\     \cline{4-5}
    \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image: Tabularx example]