# Stretching a table

Tags: tables

I want to stretch my table using `tabular*`. I'm using following piece of code. I 'm not getting a proper table. The table lines/border look strange.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

    \begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Standard deviation.}
        %\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
   \begin{tabular*}{0.75\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill} } | c | c | c | c | }
    \hline          

    \multirow{3}{*}{Reflectivity(\%)} & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Distance(m)}\\ \cline{2-4}
                                 & 10 & 25 & 50\\ \cline{2-4}
                                 & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Noise(mm)}\\ \hline
    10  & 1.2 & 3.0 & 7.5 \\ \hline
    20  & 0.8 & 2.5 & 5.0 \\ \hline
    100 & 0.4 & 1.0 & 2.5 \\ \hline   

        \end{tabular*}
    \label{tab:TLS_I}
\end{table}
```

\end{document}

[image: MWE]

Comment: Instead of posting a fragment of code, it's much more helpful to embed the fragment in a complete, compilable document so that people can play with the code easily.

Comment: Same problem as in http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6836/27635

Comment: A suggestion: If you get rid of all vertical lines in the table, no one would notice the fact that the `\cline`s don't connect all the way across and, moreover, the table would look less cluttered and thus be easier to take in.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `tabulary` instead of `tabular*` in this simpler  way:

```
\begin{tabulary}{0.75\textwidth}{CCCC}
```

Only as a matter of style, I made also some other changes ( removing vertical lines and unnecessary horizontal lines, using `booktabs` commands for horizontal lines and raising a little  the caption.

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabulary}
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup[table]{skip=5pt}

\begin{document}

   \begin{table}
    \centering
    \caption{Standard deviation.}
   \begin{tabulary}{0.75\textwidth}{ C  C  C  C  }
    \toprule

    \multirow{3}{*}{Reflectivity(\%)} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Distance (m)}\\ \cmidrule{2-4}
                                 & 10 & 25 & 50\\ \cmidrule{2-4}
                                 & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Noise (mm)}\\ \midrule
    10  & 1.2 & 3.0 & 7.5 \\ 
    20  & 0.8 & 2.5 & 5.0 \\ 
    100 & 0.4 & 1.0 & 2.5 \\ \bottomrule   

        \end{tabulary}
    \label{tab:TLS_I}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: When using the rules of the `booktabs` package, proper vertical positioning via `\multirow` becomes difficult, to say the least. In the present case, I'd ditch `\multirow` entirely and just place "Reflectivity" on the same row as the three distances.

Comment: @Mico You're rigth.  A `\multirow` have  nosense in this case. I ignored this issue.